# How can get all attributes on a property's interface/basetype ancestry?

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

So, if i have:

```
public class Sedan : Car 
{
    /// ...
}

public class Car : Vehicle, ITurn
{
    [MyCustomAttribute(1)]
    public int TurningRadius { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Vehicle : ITurn
{
    [MyCustomAttribute(2)]
    public int TurningRadius { get; set; }
}

public interface ITurn
{
    [MyCustomAttribute(3)]
    int TurningRadius { get; set; }
}
```

What magic can I use to do something like:

```
[Test]
public void Should_Use_Magic_To_Get_CustomAttributes_From_Ancestry()
{
    var property = typeof(Sedan).GetProperty("TurningRadius");

    var attributes = SomeMagic(property);

    Assert.AreEqual(attributes.Count, 3);
}
```

---

Both

```
property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

And

```
Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(property, true);
```

Only return 1 attribute. The instance is the one built with MyCustomAttribute(1). This doesn't seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a framework issue. Interface attributes are ignored by GetCustomAttributes. see the comment on this blog post http://hyperthink.net/blog/getcustomattributes-gotcha/#comment-65

Answer (score 2):

```
object[] SomeMagic (PropertyInfo property)
{
    return property.GetCustomAttributes(true);
}
```

UPDATE:

Since my above answer doesn't work why not to try something like this:

```
public void Should_Use_Magic_To_Get_CustomAttributes_From_Ancestry()
{

    Assert.AreEqual(checkAttributeCount (typeof (Sedan), "TurningRadious"), 3);
}


int checkAttributeCount (Type type, string propertyName)
{
        var attributesCount = 0;

        attributesCount += countAttributes (type, propertyName);
        while (type.BaseType != null)
        {
            type = type.BaseType;
            attributesCount += countAttributes (type, propertyName);
        }

        foreach (var i in type.GetInterfaces ())
            attributesCount += countAttributes (type, propertyName);
        return attributesCount;
}

int countAttributes (Type t, string propertyName)
{
    var property = t.GetProperty (propertyName);
    if (property == null)
        return 0;
    return (property.GetCustomAttributes (false).Length);
}
```

Comment: In the provided example the assertion fails. It returns 1 attribute, not all 3.

Comment: You're right, that's because it's really just one customattribute.

Comment: If I change the instance of the attribute it seems to only return the one on car. So its not searching after Car. See updated question. Ty for the help though.